# Как остановить по клику на кнопку интервальное выполнение функции

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Вроде не новичок в JS, но вопрос возник довольно легкий и глупый.
Как остановить по клику на кнопку интервальное выполнение функции, а затем в любое время, по клику на эту же кнопку, начать с начала выполнение той же функции. Использовать лишь один обработчик события.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let timerId;

function onClick() {
  if(timerId) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = undefined;
  } else {
    timerId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('interval');
    }, 300)
  }
}
```

`timerId` в браузере `integer`, а в Node.js `object`.